# update and save date automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi guys i am working for project in php I have `<form>` with save button `<input>` to update the data in the database

The idea what i want to do , instead  to click every single page to update the data, i want to do it automatically by using for example javascript function for example every 10 min every single page will update auto

Manually if I click Save button it will update data in DB
once i click the page i can see there is some update and it need to save in db, i need to do this automatic click save button for every single pages every 10 min

Here is an example of what i did

```
<form action="/test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="test1" value="<?= $test->from; ?>" />
  <input type="text" name="test2" value="<?= $test->to; ?>" />
  <input type="text" name="test3" value="<?= $test->distance; ?>" />
  <input type="text" name="test4" value="<?= $test->time; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?= $action ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $test->id ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?= $title ?>" />
</form>
```

And here for the script

```
window.onload(function () {
  setTimeout("document.forms[0].submit();", 10000);
});
```

I need your help guys to solve this problem it will save my time instead of open every single page and click update button

Comment: No need to write everything in bold. You ask for help with a problem, but don't describe the actual issue you are encountering. I am assuming your `setTimeout` is not firing?

Comment: @akenion the issues it is not update every 5 or 10 min i think there is problem with code that i did

Comment: Have you checked the browser console? Any JavaScript errors? Also, note that the delay is in _milliseconds_ so that is actually a 10 second delay rather than 10 minutes. The string syntax is generally not recommended as a best practice, defining an anonymous function or directly passing the submit function would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple change in your script. I hope it will help.

```
function autoSubmit(){
    setTimeout(document.forms[0].submit(), 10000);
}
    window.onload = autoSubmit()
```